# How to get longitude and latitude from the address

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps, themes

I want to display longitude and latitude in a input field using the address that user will enter. I searched a lot and found some solutions that work when i run them in local server and when i include that code in my project then it will not work. I am using Directory+ theme. This theme has feature to display map and it gives me an error

> You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

Here is my code

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
 // location types.
 autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
 (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
  { types: ['geocode'] });

   // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
   // fields in the form.
   autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

  // [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
   console.log(place);
   alert(place.geometry.location);
   for (var component in componentForm) {
   document.getElementById(component).value = '';
   document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
}

 // Get each component of the address from the place details
 // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
 for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
   var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
   if (componentForm[addressType]) {
    var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
    document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
   }
  }
}
// [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
     var geolocation = {
       lat: position.coords.latitude,
       lng: position.coords.longitude
     };
     var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
       center: geolocation,
      radius: position.coords.accuracy
    });
    autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
   });
 }
}
// [END region_geolocation]

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>
```

kindly tell me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix. It was the issue with theme's google map. To fix it, i called my javascript code after get_footer(); and its working fine.